# How to develop videoplayback software

Tags: windows, video, audiovideoplayback

I am trying to develop a video player just for fun and for the learning experience like media player or vlc. I was wondering how do media players project these video files to user? how to decode these video files into a video? samples of algorithms that can be used and any idea on languages that would be appropriate to develop such softwares.

I know this question is VERY vague but this is my first step into this section of studies and a tutorial or a nudge in the proper direction would be great. Thank you very much.

**PS** : would appreciate more information if possible :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most use OpenGL/Direct X to draw the video on top of their regular window.

Comment: thak you very much for the replyy..so what you mean is, we can use these libraries to draw the video?.. any specific language to use? hwo about the colors of the video? are they pre defined in the direct x libraries?? :)

Comment: Usually the only thing you need to worry about is decoding and getting the right pixels onto the right spot in the window. As for the language, you can use almost any language out there though this kind of work is usually done in C or C++.